# Update odd/even row colors when hiding rows

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have several tables on a page and a checkbox to show/hide rows based on the contents of one of the cells.  While all rows are visible, everything is perfect and the row colors alternate as needed. When I hide rows though, the alternating row colors are no longer correct (obviously).  How can I easily update the classes to keep the alternating row colors when the checkbox is checked and then go back to normal after unchecking the checkbox?

```
<table id='27249'><thead><tr><th>h1</th><th>h2</th><th>h3</th><th>h4</th><th>h5</th><th>h6</th></tr><thead><tbody>
<tr class='odd'><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>$0.25 </td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='even'><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>$0.25 </td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='odd'><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>$0.25 </td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='even'><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>$0.25 </td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Jsfiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/6bfjw/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few approaches to consider. Because of your use-case, the pure css approach is more theoretical, but won't actually work for you.

***In a perfect world...***

Firstly, to keep your markup loosely coupled with styling, and allow easy extensibility, favor more flexible CSS rules. There's *usually* no need to hard-code the `even` and `odd` classes on elements; that means that you'll have to add those classes every time you try and add a new element. Instead, use the css3 `:nth-child` selector:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#99FFFF;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#FFFF99;
}
```

***But since you're hiding elements without actually removing them...***

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/6bfjw/5/)

You'll need to use JavaScript, and manually manage these classes. Every time the checkbox value changes, reassign the even and odd classes to the visible rows:

```
$("#checkbox").change(function () {
    if ($("#checkbox").is(":checked")) {
        $("table tbody tr").each(function () {
            var cell = $.trim($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text());
            if (cell.length == 0) {
                console.log("empty");
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("table tbody tr").show();
    }

    $("table tbody tr").removeClass("odd even");
    $("table tbody tr:visible:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("table tbody tr:visible:even").addClass("even");
});
```

(Of course this means your CSS remains as it was originally).

Take a look at the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) on selectors. Some convenient ones are the [`:even` selector](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/), and the more verbose [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

Comment: Also, pro-tip, no need to define a `nodisplay` class and manually toggle it. jQuery has implemented two nifty methods for that, [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show) and [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide). Hiding the element is as simple as `$(this).hide()` (and vice versa).

Comment: Thanks, this helped a ton.  I updated my show/hide function to just use show() and hide() so I could use your alternating class code.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with :odd and :even selectors

Add this code at the end of the change() function:

```
$("table tbody").each(function() {        
    $(this).find("tr:visible:even").addClass("even").removeClass("odd");
    $(this).find("tr:visible:odd").addClass("odd").removeClass("even");
});
```

I've updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bfjw/6/)

Comment: This helped and worked great.  Ultimately I went with nbrooks' solution since it allowed me to get rid of some unneeded css.