# jquery :visible and :odd selectors not working properly

Tags: jquery, visible

I have a function that filters a table by typed input

```
$('#searchBox').keyup(function () {
        var key = $(this).val();
        filterBySearchBox(key);
        $('#adminTable tr').removeClass("odd");
        $('#adminTable tr:visible:odd').addClass("odd");
    });
```

The function hides rows that don't match the input, I then want to re style the table with alternating row colors. At present when a user enters a key the styling behaves very erratically, working on occasion. The filter works fine.

p.s. I'm using IE9

EDIT
    my filterBySearchBox function is below

```
function filterBySearchBox(key) {
    var $rows = $('#adminTable tr:visible');
    var val = $.trim(key).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    $rows.show().filter(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
}
```

Comment: I think you should add relevant html code with this

Comment: Also provide the code in `filterBySearchBox` if you want a complete solution :)

Comment: Does filter by search box run some ajax? if so you probably want to run the class stuff in the completed function of the ajax

Comment: no ajax, I initially had the removeClass addClass functionality within the filterBySearchBox class itself just to see if seperating them would make a difference to the rendering order

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update odd/even row colors when hiding rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770376/update-odd-even-row-colors-when-hiding-rows)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code, this may suit your need:

```js
jQuery("table tr:even").css("background-color", "red");
jQuery("table tr:odd").css("background-color", "yellow");

$("#filter").keyup(function() {
   jQuery("table tbody tr").show();
   jQuery("table td:contains('"+$("#filter").val()+"')").parent().hide();
    var $trs = jQuery("table tbody tr:visible");
    $trs.filter(":even").css("background-color", "red");
    $trs.filter(":odd").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="filter" value="">
<table>
    <tr><td>Item 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item 5</td></tr>
</table>
```